# JavaScript :: Iterate through nested JSON object and create new structure

Tags: javascript, json, object

Attempting to restructure nested JSON data (`data1`) into "proper" format (`data2`)
 with no success so far.

`data1` is generated based on a given parent directory (recipes) that looks for html files.

`data2` is what I'm trying to output using `data1` since whatever content inside a folder is better represented as array of objects than just pure nested objects.

```
var data1 = {  
   "cake": {  
      "chocolate": {  
         "black-forest": {  
            "name": "Black Forest",
            "path": "recipes/cake/chocolate/black-forest.html"
         },
         "new-shortcake": {  
            "milk-chocolate-shortcake": {  
               "name": "Milk chocolate shortcake",
               "path": "recipes/cake/chocolate/shortcake/milk-chocolate-shortcake.html"
            },
            "dark-chocolate-shortcake": {  
               "name": "Dark chocolate shortcake",
               "path": "recipes/cake/chocolate/shortcake/dark-chocolate-shortcake.html"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "pasta": {  
      "spaghetti": {  
         "aglio-olio": {  
            "name": "Spagehetti Aglio Olio",
            "path": "recipes/pasta/spaghetti/aglio-olio.html"
         },
         "carbonara": {  
            "name": "Carbonara",
            "path": "recipes/pasta/spaghetti/carbonara.html"
         }
      },
      "lasagna": {  
         "name": "Lasagna",
         "path": "recipes/pasta/lasagna.html"
      }
   }
}



var data2 = [
   {
      "name": "cake",
      "children": [
         {
            "name": "chocolate",
            "children": [
               {
                  "name": "Black Forest",
                  "path": "recipes/cake/chocolate/black-forest.html"
               },
               {
                  "name": "New Shortcake",
                  "children": [
                     {
                        "name": "Milk chocolate shortcake",
                        "path": "recipes/cake/chocolate/shortcake/milk-chocolate-shortcake.    html"
                     },
                     {
                        "name": "Dark chocolate shortcake",
                        "path": "recipes/cake/chocolate/shortcake/dark-chocolate-shortcake.    html"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name": "pasta",
      "children": [
         {
            "name": "spaghetti",
            "children": [
               {
                  "name": "Spagehetti Aglio Olio",
                  "path": "recipes/pasta/spaghetti/aglio-olio.html"
               },
               {
                  "name": "Carbonara",
                  "path": "recipes/pasta/spaghetti/carbonara.html"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name": "Lasagna",
            "path": "recipes/pasta/lasagna.html"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

https://codepen.io/kyooriouskoala/pen/LLLXmG

Any help much appreciated!

PS: End goal is to build a menu with the new data structure.

Comment: Please post your code directly into your question.

Comment: @samanime I can't post the entire code directly on the question as it keeps saying "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: Can you give a summarized version of what you're trying to convert from and to?

Comment: The return value from your recursive call to tree is not being used.

Comment: @samanime: I've added more description as to what I'm trying to achieve. Hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this output is what you meant.

```
var final = [];
function tree(object, temp){
for(var key in object){

var folder = {};
if(object[key] !== null && typeof object[key] == 'object'){
  //console.log(key); 

  if(_.has(object[key], "path")){
    folder.name = object[key].name;
    folder.path = object[key].path;
    folder.children = [];
  } else{
    folder.name = key;
    folder.children = object[key];
  }

  final.push(folder); 
  tree(object[key]);
}
} 

  return final;
}
```

This outputs your data as a associative object with values needed.

Comment: Thanks. This does not output result as expected though.